# Can a Jenkins pipeline have an optional input step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to create a Jenkins pipeline with an optional input stage?

The below snippet doesn't achieve this goal.

### Expected behaviour

The stage (and therefore the input prompt) should only run for specific branches.

### Actual behaviour

This stage runs for all branches. The when filter is ignored when an input step is used.

```
stage('Approve') {
            when {
                expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ /^qa[\w-_]*$/ }
            }
            input {
                message "Approve release?"
                ok "y"
                submitter "admin"
                parameters {
                    string(name: 'IS_APPROVED', defaultValue: 'y', description: 'Deploy to master?')
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (IS_APPROVED != 'y') {
                        currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
                        error "User cancelled"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note: Moving the input block inside of the steps block breaks Jenkins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filter is not ignored, it is just evaluated after the input step. In your example, you would always be asked whether to deploy, and in the case that you are not on a QA branch, nothing would happen.

Now you could ask why Jenkins isn't evaluating the 'when' directive first. In that case, you could not use the input parameter in your when condition.

And having multiple when directives would be like scripting within the declarative pipeline.

However, there is an expression that allows you controlling when the 'when' directive is evaluated. This is [beforeAgent](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/). It allows you to evaluate the when statement before the agent is allocated. Similar to that, you would need something like beforeInput. You could [create a feature request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/) for that.

I stepped away from using the input directive and I use input within a scripting block now, because that provides much more flexibility, e.g. I am sending Slack notifications when somebody has to approve something, which is impossible with the declarative approach. You would need a notify directive for that. And if there was one, is that going to be evaluated before or after the input step?

You see, doing everything declarative is not always the best way. So my recommended approach is the following (disclaimer: this is untested!):

```groovy
pipeline {
  // We want to use agents per stage to avoid blocking our build agents
  // while we are waiting for user input.
  agent none
  ...
  // The question mark naming convention is helpful to show you which
  //  approval stage belongs to which work stage.
  stage('Release?') {
    // Don't allocate an agent because we don't want to block our
    // slaves while waiting for user input.
    agent none
    when {
      // You forgot the 'env.' in your example above ;)
      expression { env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /^qa[\w-_]*$/ }
    }
    options {
      // Optionally, let's add a timeout that we don't allow ancient
      // builds to be released.
      timeout time: 14, unit: 'DAYS' 
    }
    steps {
      // Optionally, send some notifications to the approver before
      // asking for input. You can't do that with the input directive
      // without using an extra stage.
      slackSend ...

      // The input statement has to go to a script block because we
      // want to assign the result to an environment variable. As we 
      // want to stay as declarative as possible, we put noting but
      // this into the script block.
      script {
        // Assign the 'DO_RELEASE' environment variable that is going
        //  to be used in the next stage.
        env.DO_RELEASE = input ...
      }
      // In case you approved multiple pipeline runs in parallel, this
      // milestone would kill the older runs and prevent deploying
      // older releases over newer ones.
      milestone 1
    }
  }
  stage('Release') {
    // We need a real agent, because we want to do some real work.
    agent any
    when {
      // Evaluate the 'when' directive before allocating the agent.
      beforeAgent true
      // Only execute the step when the release has been approved.
      environment name: 'DO_RELEASE', value: 'yes'
    }
    steps {
      // Make sure that only one release can happen at a time.
      lock('release') {
        // As using the first milestone only would introduce a race 
        // condition (assume that the older build would enter the 
        // milestone first, but the lock second) and Jenkins does
        // not support inter-stage locks yet, we need a second 
        // milestone to make sure that older builds don't overwrite
        // newer ones.
        milestone 2

        // Now do the actual work here.
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `beforeInput` flag was added for `when` in Pipeline: Declarative [1.3.3 on 2018-11-27](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50880)

Comment: although where **`beforeInput`** is mentioned [in the documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) there is a typo: "by default, the `when` condition for a `stage` will be evaluated _after_ the `input`"

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be more like (completely untested):

```java
stage('Approve') {
        when {
            expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ /^qa[\w-_]*$/ }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                def IS_APPROVED = input(
                    message: "Approve release?"
                    ok: "y"
                    submitter: "admin"
                    parameters: [
                        string(name: 'IS_APPROVED', defaultValue: 'y', description: 'Deploy to master?')
                    ]
                )
                if (IS_APPROVED != 'y') {
                    currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
                    error "User cancelled"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So essentially, you're hitting the limits of declarative pipelines have to fall back to groovy scripting / scripted pipelines.