# Jenkins DSL Pipeline: delete a job from its pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that (among other things) creates another pipelineJob (to cleanup everything afterwards) using [Job DSL plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin).

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'Deployment' }

    stages {
        stage('Clean working directory and Checkout') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        // Complex logic omitted

        stage('Generate cleanup job') {
            steps {
                build job: 'cleanup-job-template',
                        parameters: [
                                string(name: 'REGION', value: "${REGION}"),
                                string(name: 'DEPLOYMENT_TYPE', value: "${DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}")
                        ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I need this newly generated job to be built only once and then, if the build was successful, the job should be deleted.

```
pipeline {
   stages {
        stage('Cleanup afterwards') {
            // cleanup logic
        }
   }
    post { 
        success { 
            // delete this job?
        }
    }

}
```

I thought, that this can be done using [Pipeline Post Action](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post), but, unfortunately, I couldn't find any out-of-the-box solution for this.
Is it possible to achieve this at all?

Comment: Why do you need this to be an extra job? Why can‘t you do the cleanup in the same job?

Comment: @HendrikMHalkow, that job creates some AWS cloudformation stack that is then tested. So, once tests are done this stack shall be removed. Cleanup job is here for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using the post Groovy and then you will need to write some groovy code in order to delete the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import hudson.model.*
pipeline {
   agent none
   stages {
        stage('Cleanup afterwards') {
            // cleanup logic
            steps {
                node('worker') {
                    sh 'ls -la'
                }
            }
        }
   }
   post { 
       success { 
           script {
               jobsToDelete = ["<JOB_TO_DELETE"]
               deleteJob(Hudson.instance.items, jobsToDelete)
           }
       }
   }
}

def deleteJob(items, jobsToDelete) {
    items.each { item ->
      if (item.class.canonicalName != 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder') {
        if (jobsToDelete.contains(item.fullName)) {
          manager.listener.logger.println(item.fullName)
          item.delete()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Tested both cases and work on Jenkins 2.89.4

Answer (score 0):

You should do that all in one job instead of creating and deleting jobs. Use multiple stages for that, e.g. deploy test system, run tests / wait for tests to be finished, undeploy. No need for extra jobs. Example posted here: [Can a Jenkins pipeline have an optional input step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821921/can-a-jenkins-pipeline-have-an-optional-input-step/48823382#48823382)

Comment: Okay, I explained it badly, I assume. Tests are performed manually and take several days to complete. This is called  [Canary release](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html)

Comment: Right. And for the long running manual test, you create an agentless stage “wait for test to be completed” with an input step as shown in the linked example, asking the user whether the test waa successful or not. So you even have the test result for further processing.

Comment: but this is kinda non-intuitive approach. What if during this testing Jenkins needs to be restarted? IMHO it's cleaner and easier to have a separate job for `cleanup`

Comment: Jenkins 2 Pipelines are designed exactly for this. They even survive an upgrade while your long-running test is taking place.