# Self-delete Jenkins builds after they're finished

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

tl;dr: I'd like to delete builds from within their execution, or rather, in a post statement (though the specifics shouldn't matter).

---

Background: In a project I'm working on, there is a "gateway" job of sorts that aggregates all new job triggers into one launch as long as certain other jobs are still running. For this purpose, this job aborts itself such that there is only ever one instance running (which is often not the latest build).

Unfortunately, this means that in the job preview, the job is often shown as aborted, which is undesirable (ending the job as "successful" or some other status wouldn't improve anything). Thus, I have two options:

1. Change the abortion logic so the newest build survives and older ones are aborted. This is technically possible, but has other drawbacks due to some internal logic, which is why I'd like to avoid this solution.
2. Delete the aborted builds once they're finished

However, this is apparently not as easy as just calling the "doDelete" REST API inside the job, and the build discarder can't be set to store 0 builds (it needs to be a positive integer). This is what I tried code-wise (MWE):

```
steps {
    script {
        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        error("abort")
    }
}
post {
    always {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'x', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
            sh "curl -X POST \"https://jenkins.example.com/etc/job/jobname/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/doDelete\" -i -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'"
        }
    }
}
```

This code deletes some job information (for instance, the console log is empty), but not the build itself. Thus, my question remains:

**How can I make a job delete itself?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins DSL Pipeline: delete a job from its pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901808/jenkins-dsl-pipeline-delete-a-job-from-its-pipeline)

Comment: @AndreiKovrov I'll have a closer look tomorrow, but I don't think so. I need to delete a build, not a job.